# MySqlCommand Command.Parameters.Add is obsolete

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters, deprecated, sqlcommand

I'm making an C# windows Form Application in visual studio 2010.

That application is connecting to an mysql database, and I want to insert data in it.

Now do I have this part of code:

```
MySqlConnection connection;
string cs = @"server=server ip;userid=username;password=userpass;database=databse";
connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);
connection.Open();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
string SQL = "INSERT INTO `twMCUserDB` (`mc_userName`, `mc_userPass`, `tw_userName`, `tw_userPass`) VALUES ('@mcUserName', '@mcUserPass', '@twUserName', '@twUserPass')";
command.CommandText = SQL;
command.Parameters.Add("@mcUserName", mcUserNameNew);
command.Parameters.Add("@mcUserPass", mcUserPassNew);
command.Parameters.Add("@twUserName", twUserNameNew);
command.Parameters.Add("@twUserPass", twUserPassNew);
command.Connection = connection;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

The connection is fine. That works.

I readed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174792/does-using-parameterized-sqlcommand-make-my-program-immune-to-sql-injection) that the way that I have now, is an save way to do query's. Is that still right?

And now to the real question. With that code above, I get the following warning in visual studio:

```
'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection.Add(string, object)' is obsolete: '"Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been deprecated.  Use AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value)"'
```

That warning is for every parameters.add

And it isn't even working, because the values that are inserted are @mcUserName, @mcUserPass and so on, instead of the values that the variables mcUserNameNew and so on are holding...

So my question is, am I doing something wrong, and what is the new way to sql injection save do an query?

Comment: use `AddWithValue` as suggested in the warning

Comment: @Habib, done, warnings are gone, but still not the right value in the db...]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

try `AddWithValue`

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcUserName", mcUserNameNew);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcUserPass", mcUserPassNew);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@twUserName", twUserNameNew);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@twUserPass", twUserPassNew);
```

and don't wrap the placeholders with single quotes.

```
string SQL = "INSERT INTO `twMCUserDB` (`mc_userName`, `mc_userPass`, `tw_userName`, `tw_userPass`) VALUES (@mcUserName, @mcUserPass, @twUserName, @twUserPass)";
```

Comment: to parameterized the query? yes.

Comment: @MarcMeesters how about accepting the answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
As Bradley Grainger pointed out, in MySQL is safe to use `AddWithValue`.
I'm keeping my answer if you get here by chance and use Microsoft SQL.

---

Please read this article, advising you against using `AddWithValue`:

https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

It says basically that `AddWithValue` could sometimes incorrectly infer the correct type. Use `Add` instead.

Comment: That article is for SQL Server. There's no reason to avoid `AddWithValue` for MySQL: https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/

Answer (score 1):

Just edit/remove some code in this part

```
('@mcUserName', '@mcUserPass', '@twUserName', '@twUserPass')
```

to

```
(@mcUserName, @mcUserPass, @twUserName, @twUserPass)
```

and Add( to AddWithValue(

Answer (score 0):

@mcUserName has to match the mc_userName in the query ..

so your parm should be @mc_userName

Answer (score 0):

This is VB code...

```vb
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", 1) 'set @number as numeric
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", "this will be a text variable") 

cmd.Parameters("@number").Value = 321  'now @number has a value
cmd.Parameters("@text").Value = "A string value" 'now @text has a value

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: i think you will find that you should be using square brackets around the parameter name so 'cmd.Parameters["@number"].Value = 321'

Answer (score 0):

should be used as such to prevent any errors set the dbtype correctly then assign

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
```

correct way to set a `MySqlDBType`

```
cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = 1;
```

now set the value