# Error when input data to MySQL via VB.Net Application

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a project that input data to MySQL via vb.net application.

But, when I want to input the data, I got an error like this :

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''',,'',,'',',)' at line 1**

This is my code :

```
Private Sub Insertbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Insertbtn.Click
    Dim Query As String
    'Query = "INSERT INTO  userreg"
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=test;User ID=root;Password=;")
    'Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)

    Query = "INSERT INTO tbl_data_pegawai(nip, nama_pegawai, tempat_lahir, tanggal_lahir, jenis_kelamin, usia, status_pegawai, tanggal_pengangkatan_cpns, alamat)VALUES("
    Query = Query + TextBox1.Text + ",'" + TextBox2.Text + "'," + TextBox3.Text + ",'" + TextBox4.Text + "'," + TextBox5.Text + TextBox6.Text + ",'" + TextBox7.Text + "'," + TextBox8.Text + "'," + TextBox9.Text + ")"
    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)

    Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If i > 0 Then
        lblMsg.Text = "Success"
    Else
        lblMsg.Text = "Not Success"
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't build sql commands using data directly from the user. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: how to use parameterize queries ?

Comment: To join string in VB.NET use `&`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/542510/656243.

Comment: Avijit : can you give an example ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734600/the-difference-between-and-for-joining-strings-in-vb-net

Comment: @user3169200 You no longer need to be doing any concatenation once you switch to parameterized queries.

Comment: Also see how to parameterise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580993/c-sharp-mysqlcommand-command-parameters-add-is-obsolete

Comment: Always use `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcUserName", mcUserNameNew);` to pass parameters to minimize sql injection/security issues.

Comment: here `TextBox5.Text + TextBox6.Text + ` and also here `"'," + TextBox8.Text + "'," ` However drop this mess immediately and use parameters ALWAYS

Comment: Thanks all, the problem already resolved.