# Connecting Database to Registration Page asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I found people with the same problem, but none of their solutions helped me.

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from Table where Username ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
```

It says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'."

```
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

something about the ToString line

Comment: i can post screenshots or even the whole code anyithing just help me out its realy frustrating!

Comment: What *is* the problem? If you've found others with a similar problem, could you link to them please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your table actually called "Table"? If so, I'd recommend choosing a different name. If you really must call it "Table", then escape it with backquotes:

```
select count(*) from `Table` where Username = @Username
```

Also, you really should not insert the raw value from your textbox into a SQL query. That makes you prone to SQL injection attacks. Instead, you should make a `@Username` parameter for the query and pass the value through the parameter.

Comment: yes its the Tables name is Table i didnt think that throu...ill give it a shot. its a school project it wont go online!

Comment: Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13581064/1299394) for how to add SQL parameters to a mysql query

Comment: do i need to make a new Table or i can just rename it?

Comment: You should be able to just rename it. Making a new table works, too.

Comment: i cant get it to load the new table and forget the old that i deleted.. im going to start it all over again  tomorow and if the problem exits i will post the full code.

Comment: So i redid the whole program and at the beginging i changed it to Net.Framework 4 i was useing the newest and some codes are diferent in that one! And i used a diferent table name!

Answer (score 0):

If your table name is table then it is causing error because the table is use as a keyword by sql
use something like this

```
select count(*) from [Table] where Username = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
```

Comment: This is MySql, not SQL server. You use backquotes, not square brackets.