# How do I prevent MySQL Database Injection Attacks using vb.net?

Tags: mysql, .net, database, vb.net, sql-injection

I am using vb.net in Visual Basic 2010 and using Query to edit my Online MySQL Database from the application (WinForms).

Here is a sample to insert a new user into the database:

```
MySQLCon.Open()
Dim SQLADD As String = "INSERT INTO members(member,gamertag,role) VALUES('" & memberToAdd.Text & "','" & membersGamertag.Text & "','" & membersRole.Text & "')"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(SQLADD, MySQLCon)
READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
memberToAdd.Text = ""
membersGamertag.Text = ""
membersRole.Text = ""
MySQLCon.Close()
MySQLCon.Dispose()
```

How to Prevent MySQL Database Injection Attacks?

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

> Is this Parameterized way also ideal for these sets of code?
>
> Set 1:

```
Dim SQLReq As String = "UPDATE members SET req= '" & request & "' WHERE member= '" & My.Settings.username & "'"
submitRequest(SQLReq)
```

> Set 2

```
MySQLCon.Open()
Dim SQLID As String = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE member='" & My.Settings.username & "'"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(SQLID, MySQLCon)
READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()
While READER.Read
xboxGamertag.Value2 = READER.GetString("gamertag")
vagueRole.Value2 = READER.GetString("role")
vagueID.Value2 = READER.GetInt32("id")
End While
MySQLCon.Close()
MySQLCon.Dispose()
```

> Set 3

```
MySQLCon.Open()
Dim Query As String
Query = "SELECT member FROM members"
command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySQLCon)
SDA.SelectCommand = command
SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
vagueMembers.DataSource = bSource
SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
MySQLCon.Close()
MySQLCon.Dispose()
```

---

> This is an edit for @Fred
>
> Set 1 is now:

```
MySQLCon.Open()
Dim SQLADD As String = "UPDATE members SET req= @request WHERE member= @memberName"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(SQLADD, MySQLCon)
COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@request", request)
COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberName", My.Settings.username)
COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
MySQLCon.Close()
MySQLCon.Dispose()
```

> Set 2 is now:

```
MySQLCon.Open()
Dim SQLID As String = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE member= @member"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(SQLID, MySQLCon)
COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@member", My.Settings.username)
COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()
While READER.Read
xboxGamertag.Value2 = READER.GetString("gamertag")
vagueRole.Value2 = READER.GetString("role")
vagueID.Value2 = READER.GetInt32("id")
End While
MySQLCon.Close()
MySQLCon.Dispose()
```

> Set 3 is now:

```
Same as usual cause you said it should be fine.
```

Are these correct? Protected from Injections?

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question.  You need to use parameters, just convert it to VB.Net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580993/mysqlcommand-command-parameters-add-is-obsolete

Comment: @Fred i edited my question details and would like you to answer that as well.

Comment: If you have another question then post that separately, otherwise we could go on all day trying to answer each edit

Comment: ok sure i could do this in 7 days as i have no more available questions that i can post on Stackoverflow. This is why i ask now cause it's related to the question and i need this answered now rather than in 7 days. Thanks anyways @MattWilko

Comment: @MattWilko no you may not post as many as you like. it limits me to 1-3 a weak.

Comment: A user may ask 

50 questions over any 30-day period
six questions over any 24-hour period
one question over any 30-second period
users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask

Comment: @MattWilko well it's ripping me off then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MySQLCon.Open()
Dim SQLADD As String = "INSERT INTO members(member,gamertag,role) VALUES(@memberToAdd, @memberGamingTag, @memberRole)"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(SQLADD, MySQLCon)
COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberToAdd", memberToAdd.Text)  
COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberGamingTag", membersGamertag.Text)  
COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberRole", membersRole.Text)  
COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
memberToAdd.Text = ""
membersGamertag.Text = ""
membersRole.Text = ""
MySQLCon.Close()
MySQLCon.Dispose()
```

You don't need to use `COMMAND.ExecuteReader` as you are not retrieving data.

You should never build your queries like this:

```
UPDATE members SET req= '" & request & "' WHERE member= '" & My.Settings.username & "'"
```

It is vunerable to [SQL Injection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx), you should parameterize your queries as I have in the example above.  This applies to any query be it `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT`

Comment: I like this format. But is it ideal for my above edits in my question details?

Comment: Set 1: pass your value into the function and set the parameter in the function.  Set 2 yes this should be `member=@member` and set a parameter as above.  Set 3 has no value to set so that is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness and great help. I'm currently now checking your answer and the one that works.

Comment: i am going to want to clarify that i have these typed up right so i'll be replying to you with the 3 sets in the format if you can tell me if they are right.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concatenating your SQL statement like this:

`Dim SQLADD As String = "INSERT INTO members(member,gamertag,role) VALUES('" & memberToAdd.Text & "','" & membersGamertag.Text & "','" & membersRole.Text & "')"`

You specify each parameter using an @ prefix like this without any quotes:

`Dim SQLADD As String = "INSERT INTO members(member,gamertag,role) VALUES(@member, @gamertag, @role)"`

Then you specify the values for each parameter like this using the correct variable type for the data type in your database:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@member", member)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gamertag", gamertag)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", role)
```

Your example edit is **not** a parameterised query. You should never concatenate your SQL string with variables.

Answer (score -1):

You should put the insert query at the Stored Procedure.

```
conn.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;

                    cmd.CommandText = "add_mem";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@member", "Jones");
                    cmd.Parameters["@lname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gamertag", "Tom");
                    cmd.Parameters["@fname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", "1940-06-07");
                    cmd.Parameters["@bday"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;


                    cmd.Parameters["@empno"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```