# confused about parameters passed to cmd.Parameters.Add()

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am going to delete a single record from report returned by gridView, I have added edit and delete buttons in a Gridview itself,
I have kept `Empno=@1` in a where clause of delete query please explain what is '12' in below line.

`command.Parameters.Add("@1", SqlDbType.Int,12);`

Comment: Its not my code I have copied it by surfing on google

Answer (score 2):

```
command.Parameters.Add("@1", SqlDbType.Int,12);

-@1 is parameter name which given in query/store procedure
-SqlDbType.Int is type of parameter 
-12 is values given to parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your framework version.Framework version 3.5 and above command .parameters.Add method is deprecated and replaced by AddWithValue.check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580993/mysqlcommand-command-parameters-add-is-obsolete).For the reason behind check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue)

Syntax is

```
public SqlParameter AddWithValue(
    string parameterName,
    Object value
)
```

Usage is

```
    string commandText = "select * from Sales.Store WHERE CustomerID = @ID;";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
```