# Creating a search function in C# Visual Studio 2013 and display results in Grid View

Tags: c#, mysql, database, search, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a search function in c# by referring to a tutorial in Youtube. But I have errors in certain areas of my code. Below are the codes for reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WebApplication4

{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    MySqlConnection old = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Database=student_record; User ID=root; Password=rootroot");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlCommand latest = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM stud_record WHERE (stud_id LIKE '%' + @search = '%')", old);
        latest.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar = TextBox1.Text);
        SqlDataReader dr;


        old.Open();
        latest.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = latest;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "stud_id");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        old.Close();
    }
}
}
```

The first error is "SqlDbType.NVarChar" with an error of "The left-hand side of an assignment should be a variable , property and indexer" so I assume it should be like this "NVarChar.SqlDbType" but when I did that, it states that the NVarChar does not exist in the current context.

The second error is "da.SelectCommand = latest();" it states that Cannot implicitly convert type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'.

I can't seem to figure the solution. I would appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use AddWithValue("@search",TextBox1.Text). Not sure why you pass a SqlDbType as param. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580993/mysqlcommand-command-parameters-add-is-obsolete?answertab=votes#tab-top). For second error please provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

> The left-hand side of an assignment should be a variable , property
>   and indexer

`SqlDbType.NVarChar = TextBox1.Text` this does not make sense logically and technically, whatever. You are assigning text box value to an `enum` constant. Also you have mixed up two ways of setting db command parameters. You should either do:

```
latest.Parameters.Add("@search", MySqlDbType.NVarChar);
latest.Parameters["@search"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
```

Or

```
latest.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", TextBox1.Text);
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand'
>   to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'

You are assigning `MySqlCommand` object to `SqlDataAdapter`. Why are you mixing two data providers. Whatever library you are using as `mysql` connector, it must be having mysql specific type for data adapter, say  `MySqlDataAdapter`, like you have used `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand`.