# Data wont get inserted into database, heisql

Tags: c#, heidisql

i want insert some data in my database (heidisql).
but it won't get inserted. any idea why?

in my table `loginname`,`email`,`algo` are `varchar`. `hash` `salt` are `char`. and stretch has the datatype `int`

```
MySqlCommand cmd2;

cmd2 = dbConStr.CreateCommand();
cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `user` (Loginname, Email, Algo, Stretch, `Hash`, Salt) VALUES ('@loginname', '@email', '@algo', '@stretch','@hash', '@salt');";

cmd2.Parameters.Add("@loginname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginname;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@algo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = algo;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@stretch", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt32(stretch);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@hash", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = hash;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@salt", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = salt;

MySqlDataReader r2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (r2.Read())
{ }

r2.Close();
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: `ExecuteReader()`?  Shouldn't that be `ExecuteNonQuery()`?  What are you expecting to *read*, especially with an empty loop?  Also, I don't think you need (or even want) quotes around the value parameters.  And is that even the syntax for parameters in MySQL?  It's been a while, but I thought it was just a `?` instead.

Comment: You can use `ExecuteNonQuery`....also `heidisql` is not a database, but, a client GUI...can you be more specific?

Comment: Omit the quotes around each parameter and use executeNonQuery instead of reader

Comment: @David depends on the database used, in SQL Server is '@'

Comment: @bradbury9: Agreed.  In this case the use of `MySqlCommand` implies that it's not SQL Server though.

Comment: @David indeed, didnt notice, but looks like '@' is also valid. Almost duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580993/mysqlcommand-command-parameters-add-is-obsolete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the ExecuteReader, which should be `ExecuteNonQuery()`, you are declaring wrong the insert parameters, should not be single quoted. Try:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (Loginname, Email, Algo, Stretch, `Hash`, Salt) VALUES (@loginname, @email, @algo, @stretch, @hash, @salt)
```

BTW, there are some databases that have different parameter delimiter, not sure if in heidisql is the '@'