# Parameterized query - multi objects

Tags: c#, mysql, prepared-statement

I found that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562747/parameterize-insert-of-multiple-rows) that is exactly what I am trying to do. The correct answer seems to do exactly what I want, but I would like to make something not to type all parameters again.

I have a `<Repere>`, with a function I already implemented for a simple parameterized query :

```
public MySqlParameter[] GetListMySqlParams()
{
    return this.getListMySqlParams();
}
private MySqlParameter[] getListMySqlParams()
{
    MySqlParameter[] listParams = new MySqlParameter[]
    {
        new MySqlParameter("idContract", this.contrat.ID),
        new MySqlParameter("contractCode", this.Contrat.Code),
        new MySqlParameter("phaseName", this.fase.Name),
        new MySqlParameter("assemblyName", this.assembly.Name),
        new MySqlParameter("idPhase", this.fase.ID),
        new MySqlParameter("idAss", this.assembly.ID),
        new MySqlParameter("name", this.name),
        new MySqlParameter("priority", this.priority),
        new MySqlParameter("quantity", this.quantity),
        new MySqlParameter("totalQuantity", this.totalQuantity),
        new MySqlParameter("listOperations", this.listOperations.ConvertToString()),
        new MySqlParameter("material", this.geometry.Material),
        new MySqlParameter("drawing", this.geometry.Drawing),
        new MySqlParameter("profile", this.geometry.Profile.Name),
        new MySqlParameter("groupeProfil", this.geometry.GroupeProfil),
        new MySqlParameter("length", this.geometry.Length),
        new MySqlParameter("weightNet", this.geometry.WeightNet),
        new MySqlParameter("revision", this.geometry.Revision),
        new MySqlParameter("principal", this.principal),
        new MySqlParameter("unloadingZone", this.unloadingZone),
        new MySqlParameter("executionClass", this.executionClass),
        new MySqlParameter("category", this.category.ID),
        new MySqlParameter("description", this.description),
        new MySqlParameter("workingOrder", this.workingOrder),
        new MySqlParameter("isMountingPart", this.isMountingPart),
        new MySqlParameter("isPRS", this.isPRS),
        new MySqlParameter("idPRS", this.idPRS),
        new MySqlParameter("importOk",this.geometry.ImportOk),
    };
    return listParams;
}
```

What I would like is using the solution there, but not having to type again all parameters (as I would like to do it on several objects, and lot of parameters).

Here is what I have for now :

```
private void insertListReperes(List<Repere> listReperes)
{
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        using (this.connection)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO [vsteel].detail (ID_CONTRACT,NAME_CONTRACT,NAME_PHASE,NAME_ASS,ID_PHASE,ID_ASS,NAME,NAME_ORI,PRIORITY,QTE,QTE_TOT,OP," +
            "MATERIAL,DRAWING,PROFILE,GROUP_PROFILE,LENGTH,WEIGHT,REVISION,PRINCIPAL,UNLOADING_ZONE,EXECUTION_CLASS,ID_CATEGORY,DESCRIPTION,WORKING_ORDER," +
            "IS_MOUNTING_PART,IS_PRS,ID_PRS,IMPORT_OK) " +
            "VALUES (@idContract,@contractCode,@phaseName,@assemblyName,@idPhase,@idAss,@name,@name,@priority,@quantity,@totalQuantity,@listOperations," +
            "@material,@drawing,@profile,@groupeProfil,@length,@weightNet,@revision,@principal,@unloadingZone,@executionClass,@category,@description,@workingOrder," +
            "@isMountingPart,@isPRS,@idPRS,@importOk)";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.Replace("[vsteel].", ""), connection))
            {
                for(int i=0;i<listReperes.Count();i++)
                {
                    Repere repere = listReperes[i];
                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        MySqlParameter[] listParams = repere.GetListMySqlParams();
                        for (int j = 0; j < listParams.Count(); j++)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(listParams[i]);
                        }
                        cmd.Prepare();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MySqlParameter[] listParams = repere.GetListMySqlParams();
                        for (int j = 0; j < listParams.Count(); j++)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters[listParams[i].ParameterName].Value = listParams[i].Value;
                        }
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    repere.ID = cmd.LastInsertedId;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to set parameter at line `cmd.Parameters[listParams[i].ParameterName].Value = listParams[i].Value;` it gives me the error that parameter is already defined.
Is there a way to do it without copying all parameters names?

Comment: How about just `Clear()`ing the parameter collection and then adding all your new ones with `AddRange(listParams)` ?

Comment: Incidentally, if you used Dapper your entire `insertListReperes` code would reduce to `connection.Execute(query, repere)` plus the lines that set up the query and the connection - you wouldnt even need the `getListMySqlParams` method; Dapper will do that bit - just feed it an SQL full of `@parameterNames` that match your property names (you seem to have this) and pass it a `Repere` instance in the parameters argument

Comment: I recommend not using case alone to distinguish method names. Also recommend not using camelCase for properties; use PascalCase please

Comment: @CaiusJard CamelCase : `A`, PascalCase : `a`, right? Why not to use them? Is this kind of "rule"?(I am new to parameterized queries) then about your first comment, if I did everytime Clear(), then AddRange(listParams), I would need to prepare everytime, right? on the previous post it is said that avoiding preparing everytime hires some time (my problem is actually this, that's why I try to make it multi

Comment: @CaiusJard about not using case alone, same question please, I saw that on tutorials 5 years ago, so I always used that. I am not doubting you are right of course, but try to understandthe reason?

Comment: *I would need to prepare everytime* - I don't imagine so - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html creates parameters after prepare is called

Comment: @CaiusJard ok, will try right now, thanks

Comment: PascalCaseStartsWithAnUpper, whereas camelCaseStartsWithALower - in general we name public things in C# with PascalCase, and local or private things (class fields) with camelCase.. As to case differentiation alone; it's not very obvious, and some languages in the CLR don't support case sens. Consuming a C# DLL with two pub methods differing on case alone would cause issues for VB, for example.. I appreciate that your methods are private, so it's only you who will be confused by them, but a "case alone" method might well be a stack overflow bug waiting to happen.

Comment: What version of (and vendor of) MySql data access libs are you using, by the way... There are a few, and I suppose I've just assumed it's the official mysql-connector.net; I can't see any reason why setting the value would cause the "already added"

Comment: @CaiusJard I use MariaDB 10.3.14 (then vendor, I don't understand what it is)

Comment: Where did you get the library that lets you connect to MySQL? What did you install that means writing `var x = new MySqlCommand` *doesn't* show a "are you missing an assemly reference?" error? Answers might be like "I opened nuget package manager, searched MySQL and installed MySql.Data 8.0.27 by oracle"

Comment: @CaiusJard if I understand the question good, I installed wampserver. At beginning I used MySQL, but customer asked me to use MariaDB, cause he would need to buy a license. transfering DB from MySQL to MariaDB was very easy so I accepted. Why the question?

Comment: The complaint is that "doing X causes this error when I use some software provided by a third party", when it seems it shouldn't error.. It helps to know what software is in use - maybe it;s a bug in that lib. If the lib source code is available it can help chase it down, but of course we need to know what it *is*

Comment: @CaiusJard MySql.Data.dll v4.0.30319

Comment: If you right click on e.g. `MySqlCommand` and choose "go to definition" do you see at the top of the window something like "#region Assembly MySql.Data, Version=8.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" - what is the version? (the 4.0 from before is the .net runtime version, not the lib version)

Comment: @CaiusJard regarding your comment to prepare first, then Clear() / AddRange(listParameters), it worked fine. If you want to put as an answer to close? Then I look now about MySqlCommand

Comment: Assembly MySql.Data, Version=8.0.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d (and thanks, didn't know about that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the problem. The error isn't being thrown on the line you said it was; it's on the `cmd.Parameters.Add` line, which makes more sense (the source code only ever throws a a"already existing" during an Add)

You've written:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(listParams[i]);
```

You should have written:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(listParams[j]);
```

By using `[i]` you repeatedly add the parameter for `idContact` because `i` is always 0 on every pass of the `j` loop

---

Note that you've made the same mistake on the lower line too, so you repeatedly set the value for idContact 21 times

---

By the way, I mentioned a library called Dapper (stackoverflow uses it for all its data access) that can make life  simpler for you. If you write a code like:

```
using var connection = ... //get your connection here
var sql = "INSERT ... VALUES(@parameter, @names, @identical, @to, @your, @object, @properties); SELECT LAST_INSERT_IDENTITY()";
foreach(var v in itemstoinsert)
  v.id = connection.ExecuteScalar<int>(sql, v);
```

It should be all you need..

Comment: yeah, you're right, sorry for mistake. Then I finally decided to do as you suggested (clear(),AddRange() everytime. the code is clearer than mine, so except if it would make earn time, I think it is better. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I also just added a bit about Dapper and how it can make life a bit easier!