# I can't Convert SQL Select Query Result to Bit

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

After the user has registered; the user's membership is saved as "passive" by default. I do this in the following way: I have a line called "active" in my user table and the data type of this field is bit and default value of this field is 0. What I want to do is: If the user has not activated his account, I want him to get warning but I got System.IConvertible error. My login.aspx.cs is as follows:

```
DataRow drlogin = function.GetDataRow("SELECT isactive FROM user WHERE email = '" + TxtEMail.Text + "'");
if(Convert.ToInt32(drlogin) == 0)
{
    string message = "<script>alert('You can't login because your account is not active!');</script>";
}
else
{
    // Login operations
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is toxic, robots will hack your website as soon as you publish it:

```
DataRow drlogin = function.GetDataRow("SELECT isactive FROM user WHERE email = '" + TxtEMail.Text + "'");
```

[**Use parameters**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7174916/2224701) and not string concatenation!

You cannot convert `DataRow` to `Int32`, besides it is a `bit` column that should be converted to `bool`. So it should be like this:

```
if(!Convert.ToBoolean(drlogin[0]))
```

or

```
if(!Convert.ToBoolean(drlogin["isactive"]))
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be using parameters, rather than munging the query string with parameter values.

Second, you can convert to the type you want, which appears to be an integer:

```
SELECT CAST(isactive as int) as isactive
FROM user
WHERE email = '" + TxtEMail.Text + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this SQL Instead your one :

```
"SELECT ISNULL((SELECT isactive FROM user WHERE email = '" + TxtEMail.Text + "'),0)"
```

Comment: I got and error in "if" code line. How can I change this line?