# Protect my app from SQL Injection

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-injection

For now I execute a search in database and display the result with

```
string keyWord = textBoxSearch.Text.ToString();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT articleCode, articleName FROM Article WHERE articleName LIKE '" + keyWord + "%'", con))
            {
                // Put search result in dataGrid
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now following [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) example I should do something like

```
string cmdQuery = "SELECT articleCode, articleName from Article WHERE articleName LIKE @articleName'";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdQuery, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@articleName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@articleName"].Value = textBoxSearch.Text;
        try
        {
            // Put search result in dataGrid
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't really see how different this is because I still have to use the raw textBoxSearch.Text value.
Am I doing this right ?

Comment: Hi, look at this (similar) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174792/does-using-parameterized-sqlcommand-make-my-program-immune-to-sql-injection

Comment: _"But I don't really see how different this is"_ then you should also read the text instead of just c&p the example codes ... ;D

Comment: But seriously: I think your parameter name does not match the parameter in your query. It should, though AFAIK

Comment: @Fildor I changed some names in my post because most of them were not in english. Looks like I missed some.

Answer (score 0):

To protect a web site from SQL injection, you can use SQL parameters.
SQL parameters are values that are added to an SQL query at execution time, in a controlled manner.

Example:

```
txtUserId = getRequestString("UserId");
sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = @0";
command = new SqlCommand(sql);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0",txtUserID);
command.ExecuteReader();
```

The SQL engine checks each parameter to ensure that it is correct for its column and are treated literally, and not as part of the SQL to be executed.

View [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) for more details.

And yes, you can still use the textbox to take in value.

Comment: DV was faster than I could comment. Link-Only answers are frowend upon on SO. Links can die. It is ok for reference to include a link, but paste the relevant parts in your answer, so it will remain useful even if the link should die.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Fildor: Updated answer to add details from reference