# How can I update password using C#?

Tags: c#

I can't find my problem. Can anyone help me to check it. I'm new in C#.

```
  public void Btnchange_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)

 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=user;password=1234");
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select Password from user.register where Password='" + textoldpassword.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count.ToString() == "1")
        {
            if (textnewpassword.Text == textconfirmpassword.Text)
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update user.register set Password ='" + textconfirmpassword.Text + "' where Password ='" + textoldpassword.Text + "'", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
                lblmsg.Text = "Succesfully Updated";
                lblmsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }

            else
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "New password and confirm password should be same!";
            }
```

I expect it can update and change my password.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing happen'. Is there a response at all? Does the data update? Storing plain text passwords is asking for trouble. Writing SQL vulnerable code is asking for trouble (especially with plain text passwords).

Comment: sorry Sir, i'm new .The data didn't update

Comment: @LauWeiqi Do you get an exception? If so, on what line? Have you debugged your code? If so, does it enter and successfully run the innermost if-block? You need to be more precise about what is not working.

Comment: yes sir i have debug it and run .It can run successfully without error but the data wont update when i press change button

Comment: C# isn't a language I'm strong in however I see no code associated with buttons. Please read comments carefully. If you set a breakpoint at the inner `if` statement, does it stop there when run? [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174792/does-using-parameterized-sqlcommand-make-my-program-immune-to-sql-injection) for sql injection prevention. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138429/hash-and-salt-passwords-in-c-sharp) for handing passwords more securely.

Comment: Also you're updating _all_ users that happen to have the same password. You should also check for a matching `userid` in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @LauWeiqi google for `Bobby Tables` to understand what is wrong with this code. Best case, someone enters `';--` to delete all passwords. Worst case, someone writes `'; drop table user.register;--`. Don't use dynamic SQL, use parameterized queries. *Don't* write your own user management code either. The proper way to store passwords is to salt them, hash them at least 1000 times with a strong cryptographic algorithm and only store the hash. Frameworks like ASP.NET Core Identity already do this correctly

Comment: @LauWeiqi finally, you're using MySQL classes with a SQL Server connection string. This code will never work, it will throw when you call `sda.Fill()` or `con.Open()`

Comment: @LauWeiqi just in case you think the password problem is an exaggeration, this is such an old and well known issue there are *many* scripts that try multiple dangerous password variations and URLs to try that could end up injecting malign SQL into a form. Just google for `SQL Injection Google Dorks`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys , i will work on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are many many (mostly) minor mistakes in your code:
>
> - use some kind of Id fields in your sql tables
> - never do an update like you did (update the field WHERE this field is equals to...)
> - create your own class and bind the query result to this class
> - when a class implements IDisposable interface, always use the keyword 'using'
> - never ever user string concatenation in sql queries!!! SQL INJECTION!!! always use parametrized sql queries
>
> Here's a simple example for your form. Let's suppose your
>   user.register table has the following columns:
>   - Id
>   - Username
>   - Password
>
> Now let's create your own class (maybe right under your button click
>   event, so it can be private this time):
>
> ```
> private class MyUser
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Username { get; set; }
>     public string Password { get; set; }
> }
> ```
>
> Then your button click event should look like this:
>
> ```
> private void Btnchange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
> if (!textnewpassword.Text.Trim().Equals(textconfirmpassword.Text.Trim()))
> {
>     throw new ArgumentException("New password and confirm password should be same!");
> }
>
> List<MyUser> myUsers = new List<MyUser>();
>
> using (MySqlConnection con =
>     new MySqlConnection(
>         "server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=user;password=1234"))
> {
>     using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from user.register where Username=@user and Password=@pass", con))
>     {
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", textusername.Text.Trim());
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textoldpassword.Text.Trim());
>
>         if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) cmd.Connection.Open();
>
>         using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
>         {
>             while (dr.Read())
>             {
>                 myUsers.Add(new MyUser
>                 {
>                     Id = (int)dr["Id"],
>                     Username = dr["Username"].ToString(),
>                     Password = dr["Password"].ToString()
>                 });
>             }
>         }
>
>         if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) cmd.Connection.Close();
>     }
>
>     if (!myUsers.Any())
>     {
>         throw new ArgumentException("No users found with the given username/password pair!");
>     }
>
>     if (myUsers.Count != 1)
>     {
>         throw new ArgumentException("More than 1 user has the same username and password in the database!");
>     }
>
>     MyUser user = myUsers.First();
>     user.Password = textnewpassword.Text.Trim();
>
>     using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update user.register set Password=@pass where Id=@id"))
>     {
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", user.Password);
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", user.Id);
>
>         if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) cmd.Connection.Open();
>         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>         if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) cmd.Connection.Close();
>     }
> } }
> ```
>
> ...and so on.